# Optimal way to replace different parts of a structured string(XML) with random string values of different lengths in a JMeter JSR223 Samper (groovy)

Tags: groovy, jmeter

In JMeter, I have a JSR223 Sampler which eventually sends a request to publish a message on a message queue.
Before I send the message, I define a variable with the message payload, like this.

```
def msg=
"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sel xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/nsmessages">
    <Header>
        <SomeID xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/com">asd</SomeID>
        <SomeOtherID xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/com">fghfg</SomeOtherID>
        <Time xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/com">sdgfdgfs</Time>
        <Trasdhjkl xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/com">sdggfsdfdsfdssd</Trasdhjkl>
        <Grtra xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/com">dfsdffds</Grtra>
    </Header>
    <Request>
        <Sel>
            <qwertyuioID xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/Sel">
                <Rgttyuiugg xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/com">12355.678</Rgttyuiugg>
                <Itthfdfdsfsd xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/com">
                    <Nafvdgrdgfsdsfsdfra>dfgsdfd</Nafvdgrdgfsdsfsdfra>
                    <Nafvdgrdgfsdsfsdfrartyhffgfds>ghfdgfdgdf</Nafvdgrdgfsdsfsdfrartyhffgfds>
                </Itthfdfdsfsd>
                <SomeType xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/com">dfgsdfsd</SomeType>
            </qwertyuioID>
            <Rhdtdfbfgdsvdfvfd xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/Sel">1234.11</Rhdtdfbfgdsvdfvfd>
            <Aregbfdgdfgdfgrh xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/Sel">1234.11</Aregbfdgdfgdfgrh>
            <EretdfTytr xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/Sel">267840528</EretdfTytr>
            <YtrewrTyresrsfd xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/Sel">KRP</YtrewrTyresrsfd>
            <DrtyyrrtTyertergf xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/Sel">2400/R/2/07</DrtyyrrtTyertergf>
            <Tewrwerewfvfddf xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/Sel">
                <Tregfdgddsggs>2222.678</Tregfdgddsggs>
            </Tewrwerewfvfddf>
            <Data xmlss="http://www.qazxsw.com/qwertyuio/ytr/xsd/v1/tresty/Sel">
                <Trans>
                    <Mij>
                        <Mars>0115.11</Mars>
                        <Pers>
                            <Rem>1234.11</Rem>
                            <Rem>67822.11</Rem>
                            <Rem>11233.678</Rem>
                        </Pers>
                        <Com>
                            <asdg>67813.11</asdg>
                        </Com>
                        <Fddfgsfds>
                            <Trasdafdsd>
                                <Trasdafdsdtra>1234.11</Trasdafdsdtra>
                                <Tarasdas>0040.11</Tarasdas>
                                <Gtrasad>
                                    <Yhtrgdfdsgsd>8796.1123</Yhtrgdfdsgsd>
                                    <Yhtrgdfdsgsd>12334.656546</Yhtrgdfdsgsd>
                                </Gtrasad>
                                <Ftyuoioyioityh prop="1234.11">fdgfdgfd</Ftyuoioyioityh>    
                                <Ptergfdgfgdsgsdgdfbf prop="1234.11">8pt0gla0ywkc7aw1g808</Ptergfdgfgdsgsdgdfbf>
                                <Transreg>
                                    <TransTher>
                                        <Cytgfhfghfdhfdhbdhrt>0040.11</Cytgfhfghfdhfdhbdhrt>
                                        <Ther prop="1234.11">2d4l6nvkenz9c70ys1dw</Ther>
                                    </TransTher>
                                </Transreg>
                            </Trasdafdsd>
                        </Fddfgsfds>
                    </Mij>
                    <Objs>
                        <Obj>
                            <ObjMid>
                                <Sel>
                                    <Tra>3333.11</Tra>
                                    <Kjasd>2222.11</Kjasd>
                                    <Nr>
                                        <ConfStat>1234.11</ConfStat>    
                                        <Nr prop="1234.11">12345678911234999</Nr>
                                    </Nr>
                                    <Reg>
                                        <Ther prop="1234.11">12345678911234569999</Ther>
                                    </Reg>
                                </Sel>
                            </ObjMid>
                        </Obj>
                    </Objs>
                </Trans>
            </Data>
            <Check>false</Check>
        </Sel>
    </Request>
</Sel>"""
```

What is the best way to replace the values inside many different tags with different random string values of different lengths between 3 and 225 characters?

I noticed that for example, this works and gives me the result I want:

```
<Check>${__RandomString(${__Random(3,255)},abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz)}</Check>
```

(Even though the JSR223 Sampler colors the code differently just up until the first encountered "}" character)

But I read from another stackoverflow answer that is not recommended because caching of compiled scripts won't be available. So I guess this will impact the script's resource consumption.

If I use the expression above to define a JMeter User Defined variable and use vars.get("varName") to bring the value into the groovy script into a groovy variable, it will get just one random value which will be the same in all referenced places and that's not what I want.

So, what's the best approach? should I write a custom randomString function implementation inside the JSR223 Sampler or import some helping library to achieve this in the groovy code or is there a better/simpler way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use i.e. [RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#randomAlphabetic-int-int-) function like:

```
def msg = "<Check>" + org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(3, 255) + "</Check>"
```

See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates) for more details.

Alternatively you can put your payload into a file and use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and [eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) functions combination to get the payload directly in the Sampler body date like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(payload.txt,,)})}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly what I was looking for! 
The 2nd part is a really nice bonus you've given me. I've used it like this and it works like a charm:
`def msg = ${__eval(${__FileToString(./TestData/payload.txt,,)})}`

Regarding this 2nd part, is it ok to reference the JMeter variables inside the JSR223 script or should I use this JMeter function in a UserDefinedVariables test element, store it in a JMeter variable and then use `vas.get()`  to bring this variable value into the JSR223 groovy script?